# Simple Win32 scaling?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a legacy Windows desktop application that uses the Win32 API extensively (some MFC and other modern technologies, but mostly the Win32 API).

I have been tasked with allowing users to zoom or shrink the entire application, with all controls, fonts, and other elements growing or shrinking together. This is similar to what the Chrome web browser (and other browsers) do when pressing the CTRL key while using the mouse wheel (wheel up for zoom, wheel down for shrink). I have been working on loading a new font of the new size, and manually growing/shrinking all the controls on the screen. But it occurs to me that there might be a better way - a Device Context function that does this, perhaps? Or something else? Or am I stuck doing this the hard way?

Note that I don't want to just modify the monitor properties. What happens should only happen with my application, and not to the rest of the desktop.

Note that I attempted to download the Chrome source code (after all, it is open source), and after a day of getting errors and googling possible solutions, I decided that coming here might be a better option.

Comment: Most people would not consider MFC (even close to) modern...

Comment: You can use device context based scaling for the parts of the app that the window renders by itself (in WM_PAINT, or via GetDC()), but not the controls.

Comment: Win32 API allows you to set the control size and the font size. You have to deal with the rest (every control position, image rescaling, etc).

Comment: An easy,  practical solution might be to have a launcher applet that changes the display settings scaling then launches the real app  (if Windows still allows that...OS settings get more and more locked down).  It won't allow hotkey zoom but the launcher app could have buttons to pick the scaling and could store and remember the last setting used.  The launcher could block on the process ID of the real app and when the process closes it then restores the normal scaling.

Comment: This guide does a slightly different thing (scales based on OS-reported dimensions, not user-controlled) but it should still be very helpful.  https://building.enlyze.com/posts/writing-win32-apps-like-its-2020-part-3/

Comment: @DaveS: The question specifically said "I don't want to just modify the monitor properties. What happens should only happen with my application, and not to the rest of the desktop."

Comment: Yes, but the alternative is going to be re-writing all of the paint code and all of the dialog sizing code -- possibly weeks or months of effort.  My suggestion makes the scaling change temporary, for only as long as this app is running, with the prior settings automatically restored.  Re-thinking the massive effort of re-writing should be on the table.  "I've been tasked" was by someone who probably had no idea of the effort involved.  Checking back with them makes sense to me instead of blindly obeying orders.

Comment: We re-wrote an app to be high DPI aware a couple of years ago and it was not a day job.  Going forward it's also meant more development work like creating multiple sizes of bitmaps for anything that isn't vectors / scalable.

Comment: @Ripi2 that's not true. Whether the system or the application scales the UI depends on the [DPI Awareness Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)

Comment: All - thanks for the responses, and apologies for being MIA. I got called away to a WebView2 issue. But I'm back.

I am aware that this is not going to be a trivial task, unless there is some magic I am missing - and that's what I was hoping to find in this query.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I actually meant, "MFC, and other more modern technologies". I am aware that MFC is fairly long in the tooth.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - can you elaborate? What DC functions exist for this?

Comment: @BenVoigt - thanks for the link. I will investigate.

Comment: SetMapMode() to a logical unit, draw in terms of those. The DC will map the coordinates to screen pixels as it sees fit.

Comment: Hi Randy, did you find any solution about this?

Comment: @mrherkar, yes I did - world transforms seem to be the best way to handle what I am doing, with that suggestion below marked as the answer. Thanks for checking in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot here depends on what Win32/MFC features your code already uses.

Win32 itself provides (at least) two different ways to do this: mapping modes, and world transforms.

Whether you can use these for your purpose will depend on what it already uses though. MFC uses mapping modes for its print-preview functionality, for example (but I have no idea whether you're using MFC print preview or not).

At least in my experience, world transforms are used much less often than mapping modes, so this is probably more likely to work out well.

Both of these apply to a DC though. Scaling things like menus and dialogs will have to be handled separately, and in my experience is likely to be a pain. Dialog boxes use dialog units, which are based on the font set for the dialog, so in theory, if you change to a larger font, other elements can scale with that semi-automatically. In reality, chances of breakage are fairly high, especially if you're using things like bitmaps (which won't scale automatically) for some of your display elements.

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate world transforms. I think I saw some mention of them while I was poking around the Microsoft docs.

Comment: This method works great, and I appreciate you making me look into world transforms more thoroughly!